# How do I determine if measurements given for a triangle will produce one, two, or no triangles?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Example: a=7, c=28, A=12º
Here is what I have so far.

[image]

Comment: Curious how you made that picture!

Comment: @SeanHill Hi! I just used my iPad and ApplePencil the uploaded it here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By, finding out the height of the triangle, you can determine how many triangles there are. If the given length is longer than the height, there are 2 cases, if they’re the same length, there is 1, and if it’s shorter than the height, there will be none.

Comment: So this is what I am understanding:                                                                                        if side > height; then 2.                                                                                                  if side = height; then 1.                                                                                                 if side < height; then none.                                                                                                                                                                                 Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Yes, also keep in mind that this is only true if the given angle is acute. If it is obtuse and the side is longer than the height, there can still only be one triangle.

Comment: I also learned another trick. What do you think?
180º-56.3º=123.7º, which is a potential second triangle.
So, I add my original Cº and my new Cº to my Aº.
12º+56.3º=68.3º and 12º+123.7º=135.7º.
If both results are less than 180º, then there are two triangles. Otherwise, there is one triangle or none.In this case, it seems that there are two triangles. Does this seem correct?

Comment: Do you mean just subtracting the angles and see if the resulting angles makes sense? That should work

Comment: Yes! It seemed that both methods worked. :)